# creating excel, powerpoint and documents in asp.net and saving the files

Tags: c#

I have a dropdownlist in my application with items document, excel and powerpoint. When i click on each of them say for example excel, an excel sheet should open and I write in it and I should be able to save the file in gridview. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [NPOI project](http://npoi.codeplex.com/). From the website:

> [N]POI is an open source project which can help you read/write xls,
>   doc, ppt files. It has a wide application. For example, you can use it
>   to generate a Excel report without Microsoft Office suite installed on
>   your server and more efficient than call Microsoft Excel ActiveX at
>   background; you can also use it to extract text from Office documents
>   to help you implement full-text indexing feature (most of time this
>   feature is used to create search engines).

Once you've written a file, you can present it for download in your GridView.  Is that what you're after?